# TestFx headless MonoclePlatformFactory not found

Tags: java, javafx, testfx

I trying to use JavaFX + Maven + TestFX (with headless)
i followed this tutorial [JavaFX headless tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V7IHHZc9Bew) to enable the test in headless mode.

my pom

```
<groupId>com.bega</groupId>
<artifactId>Chronos</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>Chronos</name>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <mainClass>com.bega.chronos.MainApp</mainClass>
</properties>

<organization>
    <!-- Used as the 'Vendor' for JNLP generation -->
    <name>dazzd</name>
</organization>

<build>
    <plugins>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
            <configuration>
                 <formats>
                    <format>xml</format>
                </formats>
                <check>
                </check>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>clean</goal>
                        <goal>cobertura</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.18.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <forkCount>1</forkCount>
                <reuseForks>false</reuseForks>
                <threadCount>1</threadCount>
                <systemPropertyVariables>
                    <glass.platform>Monocle</glass.platform>
                    <monocle.platform>Headless</monocle.platform>
                    <prism.order>sw</prism.order>
                </systemPropertyVariables>
                <additionalClasspathElements>
                    <additionalClasspathElement>${java.home}/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar</additionalClasspathElement>
                </additionalClasspathElements>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>de.jensd</groupId>
        <artifactId>fontawesomefx</artifactId>
        <version>8.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>testfx-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.13-alpha</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>testfx-junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.13-alpha</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>openjfx-monocle</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.0_20</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

MainApp

```
public class MainApp extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
   Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/fxml/Scene.fxml"));
   
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    scene.getStylesheets().add("/styles/Styles.css");
    
    stage.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
    stage.setTitle("Super Chrono");
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();

    stage.setOnCloseRequest((WindowEvent t) -> {
       try {
           sleep(1000);
       } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
           Logger.getLogger(MainApp.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
       }
        Platform.exit();
        System.exit(0);
    });
}
/**
 * The main() method is ignored in correctly deployed JavaFX application.
 * main() serves only as fallback in case the application can not be
 * launched through deployment artifacts, e.g., in IDEs with limited FX
 * support. NetBeans ignores main().
 *
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

ChronoTest.java

```
public class ChronoTest extends ApplicationTest {
  
@BeforeClass
public static void setupHeadlessMode() {
    if(Boolean.getBoolean("headless")){
        System.setProperty("testfx.robot", "glass");
        System.setProperty("testfx.headless", "true");
        System.setProperty("prism.order", "sw");
        System.setProperty("prism.text", "t2k");
        System.setProperty("java.awt.headless", "true");                                   
    }
    //bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("Bundle");
}

@Before
public void beforeEachTest() throws Exception{
    FxToolkit.setupApplication(MainApp.class);
}

@Test(expected = FxRobotException.class)
public void testAffihage(){
   verifyThat("#emma", hasText("Emmanuel"));
} 

@After
public void afterEachTest() throws TimeoutException{
    FxToolkit.hideStage();
    release(new KeyCode[]{});
    release(new MouseButton[]{});
}

public <T extends Node> T find(final String query){
    return (T) lookup(query).queryAll().iterator().next();
}
```

}

i have also add `headless=true` in my profil properties (NetBeans IDE).
When i try to build it the test bug and i got this exception :

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.glass.ui.monocle.MonoclePlatformFactory
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
at com.sun.glass.ui.PlatformFactory.getPlatformFactory(PlatformFactory.java:42)
at com.sun.glass.ui.Application.run(Application.java:146)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.startup(QuantumToolkit.java:257)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:211)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.startToolkit(LauncherImpl.java:675)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:695)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$154(LauncherImpl.java:182)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Failed to load Glass factory class

If you have any idea ?